# Shrinking or removing home partition in CentOS 7 installation

Tags: centos, lvm, partition, xfs, home-directory

I made the mistake of creating a home partition that fills up all my disk space, and it's formatted in XFS, which to my knowledge isn't shrinkable.

Since I have no use for the home partition anyway (I'm always root), can I just lvremove /dev/mapper/centos-home and reclaim the unused space with lvcreate? I notice when I lvremove it, my Free PE/SIZE increased from 0 to a large value in vgdisplay.

Thanks.

Comment: The correct approach is to be *never* root, or nearly never.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, XFS doesn't shrink.

Yes, there is no mandatory requirement to have /home as a separate file-system (although a number of reasons to do so are listed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/629439/how-bad-is-it-really-to-install-linux-on-one-big-partition/629479#629479))

Back-up the contents of /home, unmount the home directory and discard the logical volume with `lvremove` and the blocks you had assigned will be returned to the volume group as free space, which can be used for new volumes with `lvcreate` or to expand existing logical volumes and file-systems.
Then restore the back-up of /home and don't forget to remove the entry in /home from `/etc/fstab`.

I won't comment on your habit of doing everything as root ;)

Comment: Thanks! This is a test setup so being always root is for convenience sake. It wouldn't be the case in a production system. :) I have backed up /home/user, unmounted, lvremoved, and commented out the /home entry in /etc/fstab. Where do I restore the back-up of /home? Back to /home? Once I've unmounted /home, does /home move to the /root partition?

Comment: Yes, back to /home and indeed from then on it resides on the root file system. You may need to expand that somewhat if you would have a lot of data in /home